# How to Copy Private MSMQ messages from one server to another server

Tags: msmq

How can I copy private Queue messages from remote computer to my local computer?

I tried copying the .mq messages directly but that did not work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I have to create a service that will process those but need those on my machine for the verification and debugging.

Comment: You can copy *.MQ files to another machine that is configured with the same computer name. You'd need all the queue definition files too. MSMQ does a name-comparison on startup between host machine and the name in the message. If they don't match, MSMQ will purge the message.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell: Thank you for the suggestion, they only problem is machine name is different. As you said the messages are getting purged. How to handle this?

Comment: Use a VM hosted on your machine with then correct name? Alternatively, you could write an app to peek (not receive) all the messages and send copies to the queues on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

User PowerShell examples from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/move-msmqmessage?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```
$SrcQueue = Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private -Name "MyQueue" 
$DstQueue = Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private -Name "MyQueue" -SubQueue "MySubqueue"
$Message = $SrcQueue | Receive-MsmqQueue -Peek
$SrcQueue | Move-MsmqMessage -DestinationQueue $DstQueue -Message $Message
```